# Converting from List of Object to List of String using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I recently started working in Java streams. I was trying to get the String values out of the result set of one of my SQL queries. The result set selects just a String/Varchar column from the DB.

So I did:

```
List<String> list = query.getResultList().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or:

```
List<String> list =  = query.getResultList().stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I believe the map takes a function to convert data from one type to another. In this case, from Object to String and then collect them in a String list.

But the above code shows compile time error: Cannot convert from Object to List of string.

Please suggest me the correct way of doing this and explain what is wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Query.getResultList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList()) returns a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) `List` it will break stream pipeline which is heavily based on generic type information. Raw type are effectively removing all information about generic types when used so stream collector returns `Object`.

You can work around it by manually introducing the generic type with a cast to `List<?>`:

```
List<String> collect = ((List<?>) query.getResultList()).stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`TypedQuery<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) instead of a `Query`.

This does away with the rather superfluous remapping, and introduces type-safeness.